# OSM(Open Street Map) file reading and patitioning

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm new to `OSM` file format. I have a big `OSM` file which 2GB large.

What is the best way to read `OSM` data ?

If I need to separate data into several chunks and process, is there a way to the partition?

Comment: What does you want to do? You can splitup the file using osmosis

Comment: I need to partition this data file to small parts

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to planet dumps/extracts, you use osmosis to split on bounding boxes or boundary polygones. Otherwise you can query the DB via Overpass API and don't need to splitup as you can request the desired bboxes.

Comment: Osmosis is an command line java application. Can't I use it as a maven dependency in a java code and do filtering data ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to embed it in your own application. JOSM or osm2world does it like that.